# Format the date from Google Sheet Query

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to research my issue from stackoverflow but no luck. I have a Google Form with date field, the Google Form record the date in date format mm/dd/yyyy, I want to query it with below query string

```
=INDEX(Query('Form Responses 1'!A2:C&"","SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2 contains 'K'"))
```

I got the date result as integer, I tried to format the cell in date format but it doesn't work. Did any one have similar issue? Any solution?

You are visit the form from https://forms.gle/7UxioSc1ujTTyhiu7 and result from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18It_a3cHkeEfP2AHT5OQofw4mUZOpADLVB9a5jA440o/edit?usp=sharing, please visit the Result Sheet.

Look forward to hearing from your reply.

Best regards,

Kelvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a copy of your sheet and modified the formula to this and it seems to work just fine

```
=Query('Form Responses 1'!A2:C,"SELECT B, C WHERE B contains 'K'")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works if using column A, B or C but not for Col1, Col2. I don't know the different between A and Col1

Comment: When the range parameter for QUERY() is from a sheet, we use A,B,C, etc. If the range is an array (ex. comes from the IMPORTRANGE() function), we have to use Col1, Col2, Col3, etc.